# How can I install Docky 2.2?

Tags: 11.10, updates, docky, volume-control

I heard that Docky 2.2 has volume control ingetrated. How can I update my Docky to 2.2 on Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe 2.2 is still in beta. I have beta version and its running great, but beware its deemed "unstable".

Here is the dev ppa for docky beta, `ppa:docky-core/ppa`

To install it go to software sources, under "other software" add this line: ppa:docky-core/stable ,and update.

or type this into terminal:

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/ppa

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install docky
```

Comment: There is no volume-control in that preview. Do you know if there will be any? Just read it somewhere.

Comment: Where did you read it?

Comment: It has been confirmed, but not until 3.0 , https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/579712